# How to enable/disable metro app setting capabilities?

Tags: capability, microsoft-metro

How can I enable/disable programmatically capabilities in a metro app, i.e. capabilities settings defined in the package app manifest such as internet,  microphone, location, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a Google search, then I fired up the "help" on my copy of MSVS2012RC (the latest/greatest Metro-capable compiler).

Then answer is "you must set capabilities in your Package Manifest, and *only* in the Package manifest".  It appears that capabilities cannot be changed programmatically.